# Editing nsswitch.conf file safely

Tags: configuration, nsswitch

What's the best way to edit the `/etc/nsswitch.conf` file other than just using `sed -i` to edit it in place or overwrite it in total.

For our build we need to make changes to this file without destroying it if future changes occur in later packages.

I was hoping there was a tool to HELO interact with it but, that doesn't seem to exist. This is on redhat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Take a backup as, `cp /etc/nsswitch.conf /etc/nsswitch.conf.orignal`
2. Now you can use `sed -i` or open `/etc/nsswitch.conf` with some editor like `vim` and do the changes.
3. If error occurs, you can revert back to the original version,
    `cp /etc/nsswitch.conf.original /etc/nsswitch.conf`

I got [this](http://augeas.net/) tool suggestion by Ulrich in the chat which is used for editing the configuration files. From their home page, I see,

> Augeas is: An API provided by a C library A command line tool to
>   manipulate configuration from the shell (and shell scripts) Language
>   bindings to do the same from your favorite scripting language
>   Canonical tree representations of common configuration files A
>   domain-specific language to describe configuration file formats

Comment: Not really what I want but thanks a lot.

Comment: @Biff, there is no other way for editing the `nsswitch.conf` file I guess. I suppose you want to edit the file like using `visudo` to edit the `/etc/sudoers` file, am I right?

Comment: Something a bit safer.  But not manually.  A lot of the pam stuff for example on ubuntu has specific commands which interact with the config files, I was hoping this may have something similar I was not aware of.

Comment: @Biff, see my updates. I have included a tool that is specifically used for this purpose. I got this suggestion in the chat. Let me know if that serves your purpose.

Comment: Perfect,  didn't come up with that in my searches

Comment: Rather than make an ad hoc backup, I recommend to systematically put `/etc` under version control, or use a configuration file management tool.

Comment: To enable changes , please do "$ sudo service nscd reload"

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend using [augtool](http://augeas.net/tour.html) from [augeas](http://augeas.net/). Puppet and other configuration management tools integrate with augeas and allow you the safe and syntactically correct way to manipulate configuration files.

Augeas is a tool to transfer configuration files into a tree, which you can query and modify. It ensures that the modification are syntactically correct before writing it back.